# Counting number of table in this div

Tags: html, ruby

Hi i am relatively new to html and to ruby .I have a div which has 5 tables each with same class.I would like to count the number of tables in this div but it returns me only 1 table.

I tried 
puts @browser.div(:id=>  "pricingChildrenValuesJWPDIV").table.rows.length

[html elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUs69.png)

how can i find total number of tables in this :div please, thanks

Comment: What's the point of providing the html elements as an image instead of pasting the code here?

Comment: i dont know how , i just registered

Comment: @KhanSaab Welcome to SO. I'd suggest that you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially **Help others reproduce the problem**. Doing so would likely improve what your experience on SO and also the benefit you receive from SO.

Comment: @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox , a global variable which opens firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) with [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)

like this example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html_s = '<html>
<div id="pricingChildrenValuesJWPDIV">
<table id="one"></table>
<table id="two"></table>
<table id="three"></table>
</div>
<div id="none">
<table id="one"></table>
<table id="two"></table>
</div>
</html>'

# Parsing HTML document to Nokogiri::HTML::Document
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_s)

# Use XPath to find all elements (div) with attributes id with value pricingChildrenValuesJWPDIV
# and tables inside this element
tables = html_doc.xpath("//div[@id='pricingChildrenValuesJWPDIV']/table")
# get size of those elements
tables.size
# => 3

# Use XPath to find all elements (div) with attributes id with value none
# and tables inside this element
tables = html_doc.xpath("//div[@id='none']/table")
# get size of those elements
tables.size
# => 2

# Use XPath to find all elements (div) with attributes id with value foo
# and tables inside this element
tables = html_doc.xpath("//div[@id='foo']/table")
# get size of those elements
tables.size
# => 0
```

I hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately that code snippet is part of a method  and i am using that method in a hash[:children_ages] f.e .I couldnt use Nokogiri for that reason.